# Implementing a life/score system in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to implement a live/score system using cocos2d and box2d. my bodies are box2d bodies which collide as I want them to but the problem is that I have been trying to implement a score system where on each collision a life is removed or reduced from the lives left and after a certain number of collisions(say 3) the game is supposed to stop. On this occasion it doesn't but from the CCLOG I find out that it actually prints out the message I put in to display when the game manager is called but a weird thing is that it calls it forever(see the debugging window below)also it removes the object, "man" from the scene completely on starting the application.

I have a gameManager(singleton) class where in the .h file I have this declared

```
@interface GameManager : NSObject {
    int lives;
}
-(void)removeLives : (int)val;
```

and in the gameManager.m file I have this method

```
-(void)removeLives : (int)val
{
    lives -=val;
    CCLOG(@"YOU HAVE LOST A LIFE MAN");
}
```

In my main gameLayer.mm file in the update method I have this code

```
if(kStateColliding){

    if (lives > 0) {
    man.visible = TRUE;

    } else if (lives <= 0) {

        [man stopAllActions];
        man.visible = FALSE;    
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] removeLives:1];
    }
}
```

and the lives is initialised in gameManager init method thus

```
-(id)init {                                                        // 8
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
    // Game Manager initialized
    CCLOG(@"Game Manager Singleton, init");
    lives = 3;
}
```

This is a screen shot of the debug console

[image: debug console screen shot]

Also note that I have a "Man" class which is Box2d class.

Am I doing the correct thing? Please can anyone help me out with how to go about implementing this system and where and how to make the appropriate calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to [[GameManager sharedGameManager] removeLives:1] is within the else if (lives <= 0) block. It should only be called when lives > 0.

You will want to do something after the man has no lives left to prevent the if (kStateColliding) block from being called. Also, you will probably want to reset the mans position away from the object it is colliding with to prevent a single "collision" triggering multiple calls to removeLives.

Where are you declaring lives in gameLayer.mm? Make sure it is being set to the value stored in the singleton because with you current code, I dont see how it could possibly by set to 0 or below unless it is being initialized to 0 or you are changing its value elsewhere.

I would ask cocos2d questions like this in the cocos2d forums: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/

There you will get answers more quickly, often within minutes.

Comment: :Thanks man for your reply and help on this topic I will try out what you have said and will get registered on the site. I do not understand what you said in the second and third paragraphs of your reply. Please can you explain it more for me in more details or maybe give some code snippets to illustrate what you are saying.Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have an update method that is called 60 times per second (which I assume you do) and if the man is colliding with something, when you check for collisions within the update method, your code will be called 60 times in a second unless you do something to move the man away from the object it is colliding with.

Comment: In the third paragraph I was just double checking that the lives variable in gameLayer.mm had the same value as lives in gameManager. In other words, you initialized it by calling `[GameManager sharedGameManager].lives`
I would add an `NSLog(@"lives left: %d", lives);` right outside the kStateColliding if statement to make sure that variable is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks once again I will have a look at those and see what I can do there.